# Has anyone got Ubuntu Touch working on Nexus 5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-7, ubuntu-for-android, porting

I have been debating whether to get a nexus 5 phone since it came out. My only fear is that I won't like android. I love ubuntu, I know that I'd love ubuntu. So I have a few question related to Ubuntu Touch:

Is it easy or possible to switch between Ubuntu Touch and Android? Would I have to keep hacking the phone? Can I dual boot them? Would I lose my data every time I switch?

The nexus 5 isn't mentioned here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices
Does that mean it simply won't work if I follow the porting instructions?
Would I have to do a bit of hacking?
Has anyone got it working?
Will it eventually be supported?

Comment: I was going to start working on attempting a port of Ubuntu to the N5 as a little personal project. No doubt there will be an official release eventually though.